# Android: Usb storage location in 3.0?

Tags: android

My app provides a file browser.  I set the root of the file browser to: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`; which, on my Acer Iconia Tab, returns "/mnt/sdcard".  However, many 3.0 devices support usb storage.  Is there a safe/proper way to get the path to "/mnt"? (to the directory that contains the sdcard and usb storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` gives `/mnt/sdcard/`, i was hoping there would be a safe method to get `/mnt/usb_storage`.  There does not appear to be.  However, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParentFile()` appears to reliable give the parent directory of `/mnt/usb_storage`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about devices like the Motorola Xoom that do not have sdcard support then it is safe to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). The Xoom actually has the sdcard folder structure on the internal storage.

Comment: On my acer Iconia Tab, I can connect a usb storage device (like a thumb drive).  This drive noes not show under the directory returned by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().  Is there a safe way to get its location?